# ndk-build error cannot found -landroid

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

building .so file, I receive this link error.

*"C:/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -landroid"*

"Android.mk" file includes this option.

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -ldl -lz -landroid
```

And "Application.mk" file includes this options.

```
APP_ABI := armeabis 
APP_ABI += x86
```

when I set the *"APP_PLATFORM=android-xx"* option in "Application.mk" file, I can build .so file successfully for both x86 and armeabi.

OR

when I remove  *"APP_ABI := armeabi"* option in Application.mk file without  *"APP_PLATFORM=android-xx"* option, I can also build only .so file for x86.

In my desktop, there is libandroid.so file in ndk\platform\android-xx\arm\usr\lib directory...

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

If not set, `APP_PLATFORM` defaults to the lowest supported platform version for that NDK. For r10d, this was android-3 (cupcake).

libandroid wasn't available until android-9 (Gingerbread): https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html